# Не шарю за JS, но нужен небольшой скрипт

Tags: javascript

Суть скрипта в следующем:

Есть две radiobutton:

```
<input type="radio" name="is_locked" value="True">True<br>
<input type="radio" name="is_locked" value="False">False<br>
```

Нужно чтобы когда значение в True следующее поле:

```
<input type="text" name="new_chat_password">
```

Стало активным.
Также нужно чтобы данный скрипт был в самом HTML-файле.
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: https://freelance.habr.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С тебя 5$

```js
function f(){document.getElementsByName('new_chat_password')[0].disabled=document.getElementsByName('is_locked')[0].checked?false:true;}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="is_locked" value="True" onchange="f()">True<br>
<input type="radio" name="is_locked" value="False" onchange="f()">False<br>
<input type="text" name="new_chat_password" disabled>
```